# MYSQL Query for Hourly/Daily Consumption Data

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i need help with an SQL query. I have a database table filled with consumption data of a smartmeter. New entrys will be added to the satabase every minute. For the frontend i want to show daily/hourly consumption graphs. The database table looks like this:

```
Timestamp              AWATT BWATT CWATT
2018-06-01 21:33:56    13.45 4.3   2.78
2018-06-01 21:34:56    14.01 5.0   2.89
...
```

The consumption adds up constantly. So i want to get the difference in consumption for every full hour and for the actual period when the query is processed only giving the database a date or a month.

eg.

```
Timestamp       AWATT BWATT CWATT
00:00 - 01:00   x     y     z
01:00 - 02:00   x1    y1    z1
02:00 - 02:38   x2    y2    z3
```

Query is performed at 02:38.

I don't want to do the calculation after the query is done. MYSQL should do the work for me.

What i have so far:

```
select extract(hour from timestamp) as theInterval
     , awatthr 
     , bwatthr 
     , cwatthr 
  from value_table 
 where date_format(timestamp, '%d-%m-%Y') = '01-06-2018' 
 group 
    by extract(hour from timestamp)
```

The Result:

```
theInterval awatthr bwatthr cwatthr 
0           2955.33 10100.6 13434.8 
1           2963.17 10179.6 13556.5 
2           2994    10251.2 13677.3 
...
22          5702    11704.5 15944.6 
23          6876.93 12078.2 16213.7
```

this gives me the actual value for every full hour but doesn't calculate the difference between the two.

Can you help me add the missing part to this query?

Comment: Why doesn't your query have any aggregation functions?  It is malformed.

Comment: For next time, see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

One method is a self-join:

```
select h.*,
       (h.awatthr - hprev.awatthr) as awatthr_diff,
       (h.bwatthr - hprev.bwatthr) as bwatthr_diff,
       (h.cwatthr - hprev.cwatthr) as cwatthr_diff
from (select extract(hour from timestamp) as theInterval, awatthr as awatthr, bwatthr as bwatthr, cwatthr as cwatthr
      from value_table
      where timestamp >= '2018-06-01' and timestamp < '2018-06-02'
      group by extract(hour from timestamp)
     ) h left join
     (select extract(hour from timestamp) as theInterval, awatthr as awatthr, bwatthr as bwatthr, cwatthr as cwatthr
      from value_table
      where timestamp >= '2018-06-01' and timestamp < '2018-06-02'
      group by extract(hour from timestamp)
     ) hprev
     on h.theInterval = hprev.theInterval + 1;
```

I should note that the "normal" SQL approach to this simply uses the `lag()` window function, which is available now in MySQL 8.

This also uses the query as you have written it.  It didn't click that you have unaggregated columns in the `select`.  This is a really bad habit, using a misfeature of MySQL.

Comment: Thanks this works pretty nice. I just need to get rid of the last column in the result set. But what you mean by unaggregated columns? should i build the difference everytime i add new data?

Comment: @dEx . . . You are grouping by the hour.  The other columns are unaggregated.  Do you want `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `AVG()`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (MAX(awatthr) - MIN(awatthr)) AS awatthr_diff, 
(MAX(bwatthr) - MIN(bwatthr)) AS bwatthr_diff, 
(MAX(cwatthr) - MIN(cwatthr)) AS cwatthr_diff, 
timestamp FROM 
`consumption_table` WHERE timestamp > '01-06-2018 00:00:00' AND 
timestamp < '01-06-2018 23:59:59' GROUP BY HOUR(timestamp)");
```

Just a quick reply for future readers. I think a much less complex query that brings the same result as the above.